# User input into file path

Tags: python, input, sftp, filepath

Sorry for such a beginner question but I am trying to create a script that users can use to get filenames from my sftp server.  The directories are basically /files/year/month/day so an example would be files/2017/1/23.

I am trying to take user input to print out the filenames for the particular directory they want.  I think my issue has to do with incorporating the '/' into the path with the input.  But this is my first project and I could be completely off.  Thanks for any input here.

```
import pysftp as sftp

year = int(input("Enter year of event:  "))
month = int(input("Enter month of event:  "))
day = int(input ("Enter day of event:  "))

srv = sftp.Connection(host="hostname", username="user",
password="pass")

srv.chdir("recordings/'year'/'month'/'day'")

for filename in sorted(srv.listdir()):
    if filename.startswith('web') and filename.endswith('.mp4'):
        print (filename)

srv.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `srv.chdir("recordings/'year'/'month'/'day'")` line to below

```
srv.chdir("recordings/%s/%s/%s"%(year,month,day))
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Jay!  That works like a champ and gives me some more code to learn about with this string formatting.

Comment: Your welcome. If it works, you can upvote my answer :P

Comment: I have but I don't have enough reputation for it to show publicly.